# Bug in .NET MAUI Entry View for Android

Tags: android, .net-maui

I'm running VS Community 2022 Preview v 17.3.0 Preview 4.0

When I run the following XAML code:

```
<VerticalStackLayout Margin="20">

    <HorizontalStackLayout Margin="10">
        <Label Text="Name:"
               FontSize="Large"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               WidthRequest="160"
               HorizontalOptions="End" />
        <Entry x:Name="MyStoreDetailsNameEntry"
               Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
               BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
               FontSize="Large"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Start">
            <Entry.Behaviors>
                <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                    x:DataType="viewmodels:StoreDetailsViewModel"
                    EventName="Completed"
                    Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.StoreDetailsNameCompletedCommand,
                    Source={Reference myStoreDetailsPage}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Reference MyStoreDetailsNameEntry}"/>
            </Entry.Behaviors>
        </Entry>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>

    <HorizontalStackLayout Margin="10">
        <Label Text="Phone:"
               FontSize="Large"
                VerticalOptions="Center" 
                WidthRequest="160"
                HorizontalOptions="End" />
        <Entry x:Name="MyStoreDetailsPhoneEntry"
               Text="{Binding Phone, Mode=TwoWay}"
               BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
               FontSize="Large"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Start">
            <Entry.Behaviors>
                <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                    x:DataType="viewmodels:StoreDetailsViewModel"
                    EventName="Completed"
                    Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.StoreDetailsPhoneCompletedCommand,
                    Source={Reference myStoreDetailsPage}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Reference MyStoreDetailsPhoneEntry}"/>
            </Entry.Behaviors>
        </Entry>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>

</VerticalStackLayout>
```

It runs just fine under the "Windows Machine" emulator.
BUT, under the "Android Local Device", connected to my "Motorola moto g(7) power (Android 10.0 API29)", the second Entry field for Phone Number doesn't even show up on the screen.
The Label "Phone:" shows up fine, but the Entry field does not show up at all, and there is no way to click it and activate it. The background rectangle in AliceBlue doesn't even show up.

8/12/2022 - NEW INFO (below)

AHA!!! - I found a really easy work-around.
Go into the Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml file and edit the Style block of code for TargetType="Entry" and insert the line:

```
<Setter Property = "MinimumWidthRequest" Value="50" />
```

```
<Style TargetType="Entry">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />
    <Setter Property="MinimumWidthRequest" Value="50" />
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I discovered this solution by watching the .NET Conf: Focus on MAUI video on YouTube.
Thanks Microsoft for all the YouTube videos that you share with the community!!!

I do still consider this a work-around, and would still like to see this get fixed eventually.

Actually, this could be fixed right away by editing the .NET MAUI App scaffolding code to insert this one additional line into the Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml file that gets created on app creation.

Comment: I have created a sample without the `<Entry.Behaviors>` to test your code and it worked well in the simulator Android 11. Did you try to test it on the other devices?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - I get the same buggy behavior using "Pixel 2 Pie 9.0 - API 28" emulator.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - I have not tried it without the <Entry.Behaviors>. Maybe that it the culprit causing the problem. I will try that soon, and get back to you.

Comment: Is the problem on the `<Entry.Behaviors>`?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - The problem is NOT the <Entry.Behaviors>. I commented out the <Entry.Behaviors> and replaced it with COMPLETED Event Handler, but I'm STILL seeing the same behavior where the second Entry field for Phone Number doesn't even show up on the screen.

Comment: Could you please provide a small project which can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - I have created a small project which reproduces the issue. What is the best way for me to get the project to you?

Comment: Can you post it on the github and provide the link?

Comment: Here's the github link:
https://github.com/pfafft33/TestNewMAUIApp

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your project and found that the problem is the null of the entry's text, so the entry's width is 0. You can try to use the `MinimumWidthRequest` or the `WidthRequest` to make the entry show correctly.
Such as:

```
<Entry x:Name="MyStoreDetailsPhoneEntry"
               MinimumWidthRequest="200"
               Text="{Binding Phone, Mode=TwoWay}"
               BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
               FontSize="Large"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               Completed="MyStoreDetailsPhoneEntry_Completed">
```

Comment: But, it works just fine when run under "Windows Machine".
Why is the behavior so different on Android? I thought MAUI was supposed to work the same across all platforms.

Comment: This should be the different behaviors on the different platforms. I have checked the entry.width. When I run it on the android, the width is 0, and when I run it on windows machine, the width is 64. I tried to check the source code about the entry on different platforms, but I didn't find it.@T.A.Pfaff

Comment: If MinimumWidthRequest is a REQUIRED field, just to get the Entry field to work on Android, then the Analyzers should flag it as a Warning or an Error when you leave it out.

Comment: It may be a design mistake, you can also report it on the github. @T.A.Pfaff

Comment: In addition, it seems the width and the height are always set a default value to make the control looks better in the layout.@T.A.Pfaff

Comment: I edited my original issue (above) with a really easy work-around that I discovered.
Look at the original issue after the line:

8/12/2022 - NEW INFO (below)